# Regarding cancer cells and radio-frequency ablation

Tags: cancer, homeostasis

Are cancer cells destabilized if near a strong electromagnetic field over a long period of time? I read this technique of using radio-frequency ablation and heat shock to kill cancer cells. I don't know if this is viable but maybe a person could wear a device like a pacemaker right over the area of a tumor that emits  strong E.M. pulses over say a month or a year. Could this destabilize the tumor ?

Comment: Can you please add a source for this? To my knowledge electromagnetic fields have no proven effect on humans. Otherwise the use of NMR scanners (which use very strong magnetic fields) wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: a separate device could be designed if viable. Doesn't make sense to get a pacemaker as it has another more specific purpose.

Comment: There was a story today on the C.T.V. news (in Canada) , on Saturday August 9/ 2014 about using beams of microwave and an M.R.I scanner to kill a tumor ; the patient improved greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to radio frequency or microwave ablation. It works by heating the tissues up with electromagnetic radiation, just like you'd use to microwave food, but it's heating you instead. Healthy cells have better repair mechanisms and survive these treatments better. Cancer cells tend to have poor repair ability and can be killed more easily. I've heard of injecting metal nanoparticles which collect in the tumor due to the enhanced permeability and retention (EPR) effect. The nanoparticles respond to the microwaves much more powerfully than cells do and get hotter, burning the tumor from the inside out.

Comment: User 137 said 'cancer cells tend to have poor repair ability'. Could a mild virus that is not harmful to healthy cells kill a cancer cell?

Comment: Do cancer cells have poor repairing ability because most of their 'facilities' are committed to growth and repair?